# flutter FireBase email&pass auth null value

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

i have a question when sending the value for auth. to firebase from elevated button , the terminal giving Null check operator used on a null value , my code as below :

```
onPressed: () async {
                      try {
                        var auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
                        UserCredential user =
                            await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                          email: emailAddress!,
                          password: password!,
                        );
                        print(user.user!.displayName);
                      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                        if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
                          print('The password provided is too weak.');
                        } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
                          print('The account already exists for that email.');
                        }
                      } catch (e) {
                        print(e);
                      }
                    },
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens because the email address and password variables are **null**.

The **!** operator tells flutter that you are sure those values are not null. But if they are it throws an exception ("Null check operator used on a null value" in your case).

I advise you to verify that the `emailAddress` and `password` variables are initialized and get a value before you call the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` methode.

Comment: tried that but getting  Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null. from the simulator

Answer (score 0):

i added controller for the textfield and assigned them as strings to the email and password , then removed one line which is wrong in the main.dart

await FirebaseAuth.instance.useAuthEmulator('localhost', 9099);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).